# What is the URL to the new Salesforce Lightning Email Editor for use in Action Buttons

Tags: lightning, email, button, action

**BACKGROUND**

I have an action button which opens this link:

```
https://xxxxx.my.salesforce.com/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?
p3={!Opportunity.Name}
&p3_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}
&cancelURL={!Opportunity.Id}
&retURL={!Opportunity.Id}
&p3_mlktp=006
&p2_lkid={!Opportunity.Account_ContactId__c}
&p3_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}
&template_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Which opens the email editor in Classic.

**QUESTION**

What is the URL to the new Lightning Email editor?

Comment: I do not think you can open the lightning email editor like this. But you can open the url that you are using in lightning and that will open the classic email editor